# How to include default value settings in the schema for SQL Server 2008 R2 replication

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-schema, windows-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

I have transactional replication set up between two separate Windows 2008 R2 servers running SQL Server 2008 R2. I am using SSMS on the publisher server to set up the replication.

I selected everything in the database when creating the publication Articles. (Tables, Stored Procedures, Views, Indexed Views and User Defined Functions). I created the snapshot and then started the replication. Everything appeared to work properly. I did not get any errors.

However, when I look at some of the replicated tables on the subscriber, in Design view using SSMS, they are missing values in the "Default value or binding" section that exist in the publisher database.

I cannot find any settings in the publication properties that talks about "Default value or binding". I have "Replicate schema changes" set to true in the subscription options tab of the Publication Properties.

What am I missing here? Shouldn't the replication have copied any default values set in the table schema over to the subscriber?

As an example, here is the section of the replication script that pertains to one specific table in which I am seeing this problem.

```
exec sp_addarticle @publication = N'Main_All', @article =    N'Piece_Details2', @source_owner = N'dbo', @source_object = N'Piece_Details', @type = N'logbased', @description = N'', @creation_script = N'', @pre_creation_cmd = N'drop', @schema_option = 0x000000000803509F, @identityrangemanagementoption = N'none', @destination_table = N'Piece_Details', @destination_owner = N'dbo', @status = 24, @vertical_partition = N'false', @ins_cmd = N'CALL [sp_MSins_dboPiece_Details]', @del_cmd = N'CALL [sp_MSdel_dboPiece_Details]', @upd_cmd = N'SCALL [sp_MSupd_dboPiece_Details]'
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my last answer as I gave a wrong response for your replication type.  When you select the articles for the publication there is a setting to **copy default value specifications** to the subscriber the value is false by default. Setting that value to true should ensure the constraint is applied on the subscriber. See "Article Properties" when selecting your articles. You can apply to all or one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Do you know of any way to edit an existing publication to apply this change?

Comment: You can look into sp_changearticle, however, a new snapshot will be required for your article change to replicate.

Comment: I decided to go with recreating the publication and selecting the correct properties as you suggested. Thanks for all of your help.